# How can i use an analyser created from an audioContext to detect if a playing sound is audible?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio, web-audio-api

First I'll describe my problem, I'm creating an automated playlist from random songs, some of the songs have 10-15 seconds of silence at the end of the song, what I'm trying to achieve is to detect from the analyser when a song has been in silence for 5 seconds and act on that.

So far I've got this:

```
var context, analyser, source, audio;
context = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
analyser = context.createAnalyser();
audio = new Audio();

source = context.createMediaElementSource(audio)
source.connect(analyser);
analyser.connect(context.destination);

var playNext = function() {
    var pickedSong;
    // chooses a song from an api with several 
    // thousands of songs and store it in pickedSong
    audio.src = pickedSong;
    audio.play();
}

audio.addEventListener('ended', playNext);

playNext();
```

I know the answer is somewhere in the analyser but I haven't found any coherence in the data returned from It.

I can do something like this:

```
var frequencies = new Float32Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
analyser.getFloatFrequencyData(frequencies);
```

and the frequencies var would contain 2048 keys each with a random(to me) number (-48.11, -55, -67, etc...), do these numbers mean anything related to the perceived sound that is played?, how can i detect if it's low enough that people would think nothing is playing.

For the detection I mainly want something like this:

```
var isInSilence = function(){
    return !audible;
}

var tries = 0;

var checker = function() {
    tries = isInSilence() ? tries + 1 : 0;
    if(tries >= 5) playNext();
    setTimeout(checker, 1000);
}

checker();
```

The only missing part is detecting if the song is currently silent or not, any help would be appreciated.

**Edit:**

based on william's answer i managed to solve it by doing it this way:

```
var context, compressor, gain, source, audio;
context = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
compressor = context.createDynamicsCompressor();
gain = context.createGain();
audio = new Audio();

source = context.createMediaElementSource(audio)

// Connecting source directly
source.connect(context.destination);

// Connecting source the the compresor -> muted gain
source.connect(compressor);
compressor.connect(gain);
gain.connect(context.destination);

gain.gain.value = 0; // muting the gain
compressor.threshold.value = -100;

var playNext = function() {
    var pickedSong;
    // chooses a song from an api with several 
    // thousands of songs and store it in pickedSong
    audio.src = pickedSong;
    audio.play();
}

audio.addEventListener('ended', playNext);

playNext();

var isInSilence = function(){
    return compressor.reduction.value >= -50;
}

var tries = 0;

var checker = function() {
    tries = isInSilence() ? tries + 1 : 0;
    if(tries >= 5) playNext();
    setTimeout(checker, 1000);
}

checker();
```

Comment: You can use ctx.source.stop(0) or something like that

Comment: context.source is undefined

Comment: You can try http://toys.eise.cz/Equaliser, there is function stop, that will stop the music try to find it there if you fail I'll try to get it myself

Comment: I am not sure if you realize but this will skip songs that have some silence in middle of the song.

Comment: True... You would have to check for time in song... My code does that too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a possible solution using a different approach - the compressor node. It's a brief description but should be enough to let you fill in the details for your use case:

Create a compressor node and connect your input source to it.
Then connect the compressor to a gain node and mute the gain node ( set it to zero). Connect the gain node to the `audioContext.destination`

Take your input source and connect it to `audioContext.destination`.

Set the compressor property values to detect the signal  (so that it triggers the reduction value ).

Wrap `compressor.reduction.value` in a `setInterval` or `requestAnimationFrame` to check for changes.

Code the logic needed to do whatever you want when this value changes ( or doesn't change ).

Comment: muting the gain mutes the destination sound, also the compresion reduction value measures the amount of reduction done with the compressor not the audio itself, am i missing something?

Comment: Muting the gain in this case mutes the sound going through the compressor but this is desirable because in this case you do not want to hear the sound that is affected by the compressor , you are only using the compressor as a tool to detect the signal. You will still hear the initial sound because it is connected to the audio context directly.You're right that the compressor does not "measure the audio itself" but you can still use it to detect if a signals amplitude goes over or below a certain threshold which is what you want.

Comment: so i should connect the audio to the destination directly and then also connect it to the compressor for measuring?

Comment: Yes, and then connect the compressor to a gain node and mute the gain node, then connect the gain node to the audio context

Answer (score 1):

For future reference - the values the analyzer returns for getFloatFrequencyValues are decibels of that particular signal - so "0" would be a hypothetical full signal, "-96" is well below normal dynamic range for a human.

It's probably easier for you to just use getByteFrequencyValues, which pre-munges values into 0-255; 0 is a reasonable noise floor.  If you're looking for REALLY silence, just look for zeros in all the analyser bins - if you're looking for a quiet signal, the default -100 for minDecibels is probably too low, so look for a low number (10 or less? you'd have to experiment).  Or change minDecibels - see the spec.